# How to remove preprocessor flags defined by Makefile Project Creator for VS9

Tags: visual-studio, makefile, ace

I'm attempting to build a static library (.lib configuration) with Makefile Project Creator (MPC) for Visual Studio 9. I have the configuration (*.mpc) files written for the GNU build environment, but I'm trying to compile cross platform with VS9.

I want to remove the preprocessor `ACE_AS_STATIC_LIBS;TAO_AS_STATIC_LIBS;` flags from the generatoed solution file, but I don't know what to change in the MPC template file (*.mpt).

I've tried to find the flags via a `grep` in the `$(ACE_ROOT)/MPC` directory but the search was inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove them by subtracting them from 'staticflags':

```
project: ... {

  staticflags -= ACE_AS_STATIC_LIBS TAO_AS_STATIC_LIBS


}
```